# Deployment to cloudfoundry from jenkins in Cloudbees

Tags: jenkins, cloud-foundry, cloudbees

Is it possible to deploy a grails application to cloudfoundry from a jenkins build hosted in Cloudbees?

Answer (score 7):

CloudFoundry has plugins for both Maven and Grails, so I see no reason why you could not. Have a look at http://blog.springsource.com/2011/04/12/one-step-deployment-with-grails-and-cloud-foundry/ for further details. I’m assuming you can run the `grails` command as part of your Jenkins build.